# How to convert decimal point?

Tags: java, decimal

I'm trying to make Stock calculator. And honestly, I don't know how to use

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
```

correctly.

I'm trying to change profit value to 2 decimal point and I have no idea what I need to do. Also, String sellOut value is not showing up at all. 
Could you please help me to figure this out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

 public class Assignment
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

File dataFile = new File ("Feb13StockData.txt");
if(!(dataFile.exists()))
{
  System.out.println("invalid file");
  System.exit(0);
}
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (dataFile);
String stock;
int pp, sp, ns;
double pc, sc;
String sell;
double profit;



//read first student record.
//for(int i = 1; i<= 4; i++)
System.out.println("Stock \t\t"+"PP \t\t"+"SP \t\t"+"PC \t\t"+"SC \t\t"+"NS \t\t"+"sellOut \t\t"+"profit \t\t");
while (fileInput.hasNext()){

stock = fileInput.nextLine();
pp = fileInput.nextInt();
sp = fileInput.nextInt();
pc = fileInput.nextDouble();
sc = fileInput.nextDouble();
ns = fileInput.nextInt();
sell = fileInput.nextLine();
profit = ProfitOut(pp,sp,pc,ns,sc);

printToScreen(stock,pp,sp,pc,sc,ns,sell,profit);


//System.out.println(student + "\t\t" + stYear + "\t\t" + gpa+ "\t\t" + credits);

//discard BOL CHARACTOR
fileInput.nextLine();
}

fileInput.close();
}


 public static void printToScreen(String stockOut, int ppOut, int spOut, double pcOut, double scOut, int nsOut, String sellOut, double profit){

System.out.println(stockOut+ "\t\t" + ppOut +"\t\t" + spOut+"\t\t" +pcOut+"\t\t" +scOut+"\t\t"+ nsOut+"\t\t"+sellOut+"\t\t"+profit );


}
  public static double ProfitOut (int pp, int sp, double pc, int ns, double sc)
  {
    double profit;
    return profit = ((ns * sp) - sc) - ((ns *pp) + pc);
  }


 }
```

String sell is not working properly. `N` or `Y` is not showing up at all.

**Here is my file.**

> AXC
>   25
>   54
>   9.11
>   6.98
>   20
>   N
>   CLR
>   24
>   44
>   9.68
>   8.63
>   50
>   N
>   UPQ
>   38
>   52
>   4.95
>   5.24
>   30
>   Y
>   SLS
>   46
>   51
>   7.29
>   4.95
>   50
>   y
>   MOP
>   20
>   32
>   4.95
>   6.58
>   50
>   N
>   NRK
>   19
>   43
>   5.25
>   7.74
>   60
>   N
>   COP
>   48
>   29
>   6.62
>   5.06
>   30
>   Y
>   SRY
>   19
>   52
>   4.95
>   9.32
>   50
>   N
>   MPL
>   25
>   36
>   8.3
>   4.95
>   20
>   y
>   RRZ
>   24
>   51
>   4.95
>   5.46
>   20
>   N
>   XON
>   14
>   33
>   4.95
>   7.41
>   40
>   N
>   LSW
>   18
>   50
>   4.95
>   4.95
>   30
>   N

Answer (score 1):

You can format the value with the DecimalFormat class:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
System.out.println(df.format(PI));
```

**OR**

Rounding `Doubles` with `BigDecimal`
To round doubles to n decimal places, we can write a helper method:

```
private static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(value));
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

You can use above method to make any value at any point of decimal value.